# python flask single page search and result with pagination

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a small flask app, a single table with several columns and what I try to do seems also simple: A single webpage showing the form based query and the results afterwards. It works fine. Next step was including pagination (due to the amount), but than I run in a issue:

```
@archive.route('/searchEvents/', methods=['GET','Post'])
def searchEvents():
    form = SearchEvents()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    #... somew other stuff...
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    results = Event.query.filter(*args).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
    return render_template('archive/search.html',form=form,results=results)
return render_template('archive/search.html', form=form)
```

from template:

```
search part:
<form method="POST" class="form-register" action={{url_for('archive.searchEvents')}}>
some other fields
<td colspan="3">{{ form.submit(class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary") }}</td>

<!-- Section for Resultdata-->
{% if results %}
{% for item in results.items %}
 resultdata
{% endfor %}
   <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
 <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
   {% for page_num in results.iter_pages(left_edge=1, right_edge=1, left_current=1, right_current=2) %}
      {% if results.page == page_num %}
      <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" href="{{ url_for('archive.searchEvents', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
      </li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="{{url_for('archive.searchEvents', page=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
{%  endif %}
```

I guess I did mess up with get and post, but right now, I just don`t see it. First result page will be shown, but it seems a problem with the next page.

Thanks for any tips or hints !!!!

Comment: Your code is not clear. Edit it and fix the tabs. is the first return under form.validate_on_submit()?

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the href of the next page is a static string, you have to concat into that string a variable that holds the new number.

Second of all you have to make sure that when the user clicks the next link, when rendering the HTML template you have to send it the next number so that its updated for the next page load.

Comment: i see a "GET /searchEvents/?page=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
so it seems he got the right thing to do, just ignoring something else

Comment: Try printing out in the server's terminal the pages with each request to make sure you're receiving the correct parameter and that you're extracting it correctly from the request